# Can cells get burned in EPROM by programming twice?

Tags: eprom

I have ordered my monthly electronic components dosage online, due to the covid-19 disease... in my dosage and for the first time I got an UV EPROM and started a personal challenge of programming it myself without following any tutorials because 1. I didn't find any tutorials on my UV EPROM and 2. I wanted to understand the datasheet for the first time, as you might know I am in secondary school not yet entered a college, yet I love electronic engineering and ask questions, search for courses etc... but anyways I have successfully followed the datasheet and programed my EPROM using 12V and pulsing the correct pulse time which was a great achievement for me !!! Yet I wanted to program another address but unfortunately as my setup was so crude, no switches or anything just generic hanging jumper wires on a breadboard, I forgot to change the address and programed again that address with new data bits, I quickly shutdown everything and when I toggle read mode on that memory address all bits were zero ! My PROM is "M27C256B" and I don't know if I have burned this address or no ..... I tried programming another address and it worked, yet I am now very nervous about the bits I reprogrammed unintentionally again.

In short, if an address on an EPROM is programed twice with different data bits, will that address get burned forever? Or just the EPROM need to get UV cleared?(I couldn't test as I didn't have enough amount of UV LEDs to successfully try clearing the PROM)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing twice to the same data bit shouldn't change anything in the long run.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well I don't know really if this is odd enough, but The first time I programed the address with 10101010 and the second time with 01010101 so maybe the zeros I saw were actually flipped ones ? in total it's 11111111 ?

Comment: If you don't have a UV light, direct sunlight for a week or so will erase it.

Comment: You really don't want to manually produce an EPROM write pulse, there is a life to consume.  Even if everything else is manual you want some sort of one shot timef pulser.  But that may not be your immediate problem

Comment: @ChrisStratton  yeah thanks for the note .... I actually was trying manually but of course I will use an Arduino or so to get everything programed in the future, also I just used an RC circuit to get the negative ~100uS pulse on the E pin of the PROM ...

Comment: I don't think you will be able to erase a UV EPROM with cheap 405nm LEDs. UVC LEDs are very expensive. The usual approach is to use a germicidal UV discharge lamp.

Comment: You can only program bits to 0, so first you programmed the even ones, then the odd ones. After which you got exactly the result you should expect. Erase (UV) should restore them all to 1. (Patching a program by only clearing bits used to be an art form)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MC27C256 and similar UV EPROM cells are at a logic '1' when bulk erased by exposure to UV light, and a cell can be electrically written to a logic '0'. Re-writing a cell that is already '0' to another '0' has no effect, and attempting to re-write a '0' cell to a '1' will be unsuccessful. Once a cell has been set to logic '0' it remains '0' until the entire EPROM is erased to all '1's.

By the way, the same silicon chip that is in the UV EPROM may also be sold at a lower price in plastic package as OTP (One Time Programmable); it's the same chip except it can't be erased because of the lower-cost packaging. The little window on the top of the UV EPROM package is made of quartz crystal, and it has to be encased in a package that has the same temperature coefficient of expansion, so plastic is out and metal is out, it has to be ceramic. The cost difference is significant.

Back in the day, we used UV EEPROMs for firmware development, and once the firmware was pretty stable we'd switch to the cheaper OTP for building up a larger batch of prototypes or building production boards.

The normal cycle involved plugging the EPROM into a device programmer to write the memory image, then cover the window with an opaque removable paper label (both to identify the firmware version and protect against stray UV light possibly eroding the image). Then unplug from the device programmer and plug into the target board for testing. More changes needed? Then put another EPROM into the device programmer, write image, label it, unplug the old EPROM and plug in the new EPROM into the target board. Then scrape off the sticky label from the old EPROM, clean off the window, and put it in the UV eraser like stacking dirty dishes in the dishwasher, until there are enough to run a full cycle. The UV bulb has a limited lifetime, so you want to erase as many EPROMs as you can with each 20 minute cycle.

All this changed for the better once Electrically Erasable (EEPROM) became widely available; no more need to pull EPROMs from the sockets and bake for 20 minutes in the UV eraser bin. Eliminated the need for the UV bulbs, the sockets themselves and the plugging and unplugging, so developers were willing to pay a premium for EEPROM.

Comment: Lonnnnnnnnnnnnng ago: Place EPROMS on brick window ledge to erase in sun. Observe ESD safe procedures transferring to & fro. Bulb life is VERY long. Note significant failure rate of EPROMS. Place on metal sheet on brick window ledge. Failure rate drops to zero. ESD seemed to love the warm toasty + brick conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can program unprogrammed bits at any address.  Whether it causes any bits to become permanently programmed depends.

Programming subjects the oxides to high electric fields.  Those fields can cause new electron traps to be formed, in addition to those that were created by "normal" defect mechanisms.

A side effect of programming the same addresses multiple times is that defects on the surface of the non-floating gate, called asperities, can generate electric fields high enough in other bits (not being programmed), on the same row to cause electrons on those floating gates to obtain sufficient energy to pass through the oxide.  Atmel documented this phenomenon as programming erase.